# C# MongoDB FindAsync never returns on Await

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

There are other questions like this one but non relating to the actual FindAsync from what I can tell.

My `ClientsController` calls `ClientService.GetClients` which uses the mongo drivers to query a mongodb on Azure.

Stepping through the debugger it gets up to the point where I call `clientCollection.FindAsync`. If I step over this the line following is never hit and no errors are given. It's like the awaited task never returns.

```
public async Task<List<Client>> GetClients(SearchRequestDTO searchRequest)
{
  var response = new List<Client>();

  var db = _databaseUtilityService.GetCoreDatabase();
  var clientCollection = db.GetCollection<Client>(Properties.Settings.Default.ClientCollectionName);

  var cursor = await clientCollection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument());

  while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
  {
    response.Concat(cursor.Current.ToList());
  }

  return response;
}
```

What would be the reason why the debugger never steps over the `var cursor = ...` line ?

Edit-

I can instead get `Result`-

`var cursor = clientCollection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()).Result;`

But I'm not sure that's what I want to do.

```
public async Task<List<Client>> GetClients(SearchRequestDTO searchRequest)
{
  var db = _databaseUtilityService.GetCoreDatabase();
  var clientCollection = db.GetCollection<Client>(Properties.Settings.Default.ClientCollectionName);
  var results = clientCollection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()).Result;

  return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the next line. Most likely the debugger loses track of the task continuations when there are thread switches involved.

Comment: Sounded like that would be it. But it never hits the next line when I `Continue`

Comment: Does it work with synchron call? If you call Find() and iterate over Cursor with MoveNext, do you get any documents? Or is your collection empty?

Comment: Synchronous call does work. The collection has 1 item in it.

Comment: What driver version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much information about context, so I came up with mock classes to satisfy question.

Please see below an overloaded method and when called, it will always return you list of three records. Now what's wrong with your code? I believe it's in your while loop. You are calling `response.Concat` which is causing an issue.
I'm calling `response.AddRange` instead and it works.

```
public async Task<List<Client>> GetClients()
{
    var mongoUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri);

    var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("ClientDB");
    var clientCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Client>("Clients");

    // Empty collection to always get accurate result.
    clientCollection.DeleteMany(new BsonDocument());

    // Insert some dummy data
    clientCollection.InsertOne(new Client() {Address = "One street, some state", ZipCode = 11111});
    clientCollection.InsertOne(new Client() { Address = "2nd street, some state", ZipCode = 22222 });
    clientCollection.InsertOne(new Client() { Address = "Third street, some state", ZipCode = 33333 });

    var response = new List<Client>();
    var cursor = await clientCollection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument());

    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        response.AddRange(cursor.Current);
    }

    return response;
}
```